# How to hide views in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a complex layout for my iOS app and want to hide some view in some conditions.

I've tried to hide it using `.isHidden = true`, but the result is not as my expectation. Is it possible to completely hide view inside our layout in iOS like how we hide view in Android by using 
**`VIEW.GONE`**?

Comment: You probably want to removeFromSuperview()

Comment: set clip to bounds = true to the view which you want to hide, may be view is hide using above code but the inside subviews of that view is show due to clip to bounds not set.

Answer (score 2):

Always use `UIStackView` for typically show/hide conditions.

> The stack view automatically updates its layout whenever views are added, removed or inserted into the arrangedSubviews array, or whenever one of the arranged subviews’s isHidden property changes.

```
// Appears to remove the first arranged view from the stack.
// The view is still inside the stack, it's just no longer visible, and no longer contributes to the layout.
let firstView = stackView.arrangedSubviews[0]
firstView.isHidden = true
```

So that's it only one line of code and your view will hide completely like `VIEW.GONE` in android.

Answer (score 0):

Create one constraint with 999 priority which shows the view when its not hidden and a second constraint with 1000 priority which makes the view hidden(height = 0 or sth similar), but have the second constraint disabled until you activate it to hide the view.

The 1000 will override the 999.